# Where to make an API call to populate a view with data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create a view that displays results from an API call, however I keep on running into multiple errors.

My question is basically where is the best place to make such an API call.

Right now I am "trying" to load the data in the "init" method of the view like below.

```
struct LandingView: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @State var user1: User
    @State var products: [Product] = []
    
    init(_ viewRouter : ViewRouter, user: User) {
        
        
        self.user1 = user
        _viewRouter = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewRouter)
        
        ProductAPI().getAllProducts { productArr in
            self.products = productArr
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        tabViewUnique(prodArrParam: products)
    }
}
```

I keep on getting an "escaping closure mutating self" error, and while I could reconfigure the code to stop the error,I am sure that there is a better way of doing what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var results = [TaskEntry]()
  
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.title)
            }
// this one onAppear you can use it
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
  
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos") else {
            print("Your API end point is Invalid")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = response
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

In .onAppear you can make api calls